# .split() function does not seem to work for the selected text

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I tried below but for some reason the .split doesnt seem to work either, i also tried the same code on online compilers and the split method doesnt work...

```
postExpireDate = (driver.find_element_by_css_selector( 'time.entry-date updated')).text.split("(").replace(開催期間：)
```

I was wondering if there is a way to extract the date period upon detection of certain words or symbol

e.g start taking record after "開催期間:" until coming upto " (" resulting in 2021年4月1日 ～ 2022年3月31日

e.g Start taking record after "最終更新日：" and stop until coming upto ")" or the end of line

Comment: Is the snippet copied exactly from your code? It seems that the characters you used aren't surrounded by quotations. Were there any errors upon running your code?

Comment: Your `driver.find_*` is surrounded by an extra set of parenthesis which is likely causing issues too.

Comment: @12944qwerty thanks for your input much appreciated

Comment: @JeffC thanks alot as always much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Never in my wildest dreams did i have an even a hint of the answer

" ( " (In ENG KEYPAD) & " ( " (In other language keyboard) IS DIFFERENT....

TLDR: just use copy and paste... do not type because the compiler takes it as different variable...